# Nuxt/Vuejs - How to create utils that have access to modules?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using asiox/vuejs to create a webpage. However I want to compartmentalize the code more. One example is I use axios to make requests to the backend, and the data in the response is commited into vuex.

```
this.$axios.get('events').then((response) => {
  this.$store.commit('data/populate', response.data)
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.error(e)
})
```

I want to write a util method for this, like `this.$populate.events()`

I have tried creating utils inside the `plugins/` directory, but they dont have access to `this.$axios` or `this.$store`

Note that I have `axios` and `vuex` imported in `nuxt.config.js`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you need the function in the `context`, Vue instances and maybe even
>   in the Vuex store, you can use the inject function, which is the
>   second parameter of the plugins exported function.
>
> Injecting content into Vue instances works similar to when doing this
>   in standard Vue apps. The `$` will be prepended automatically to the
>   function.

[Reference](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#combined-inject)

```
export default ({ app, store }, inject) => {
  inject("populate", () => {
    app.$axios
      .get("events")
      .then(response => {
        store.commit("data/populate", response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  });
};
```

`app` variable is `context` property.

> The root Vue instance options that includes all your plugins. For
>   example, when using `axios`, you can get access to `$axios` through
>   `context.app.$axios`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out not 5 minutes after posting ...

Basically [use this nuxt guide](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#combined-inject)

And replace `this` with `app` in the method you'd like to move